# Inserting a string 'india's' into a sql database

Tags: sql, database

I have a table xyz(name varchar(200))
i wanted to insert names such as
1.ramu's
2.shyam's
when i try to insert using insert as
it is throwing an error

```
quoted string not properly terminated 

insert into  xyz values('ramu's');
```

Comment: what database?  pl/sql is not mysql.  Please only use relevant tags.  If you want an embedded quote then you need to escape it with two quotes ''

Comment: use paramaterized queries or the appropriate escape characters.  (doubling up ' so it's `insert into  xyz values('ramu''s');` should work in this case.)  But lets say a user passed in `';drop table xyz;--'`  instead of `ramu's` what would happen? https://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: This quoting issue is the same in all flavors of SQL, so the solution works in MySQL, PL/SQL, Redshift, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The following will be helpful

```
INSERT INTO Xyz VALUES('Ram''s')
```

For one single quote, place two single quotes.